# Grandstream + Twilio

Tags: twilio, voip

We have a Grandstream UCM6102 IP-PBX and a twilio account that were are having issues with. We cannot get the device to register with Twilio and we cannot make out bound calls. We believe the issue lies with the VoiP Trunk settings and more specifically with the username/password/AuthID section. We aren't 100% positive what need to go into these sections. We used Twilios guide to setting up the Grandstream to work with it. (https://www.twilio.com/resources/images/docs/Grandstream-Twilio.pdf) but it doesn't say what exactly to use for the Username/Password/AuthID and we've tried various combinations using the Twilio account name/ Phone number without much luck. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I recommend sending an email into our support team at help@twilio.com. They should be able to point you in the right direction for authing with Twilio.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question.